# NSnotifiaction doubts

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotifications

I have a `UISwitchcontroller` in my setting page to change the image in main page. So I put a notification from setting page to main page. But only one notification I active every time, my setting page switch code look like this:

```
-(IBAction)_clickswitchlowlight:(id)sender
{
    
if(switchControll.on){
    
    [switchControll setOn:YES animated:YES];
  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_lowlighton object:nil];
   

    
}
else{
    [switchControll setOn:NO animated:YES];
  
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_lowlightoff object:nil];

}
}
```

In my main page.h..I write this code:

```
extern NSString * const NOTIF_lowlighton;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_lowlightoff;
```

In .m above the implementation of main page I write this:

```
NSString * const NOTIF_lowlighton = @"lowlighton";
NSString * const NOTIF_lowlightoff = @"lowlightoff";
```

In `viewwillappear` I write this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(clicklowlighton:) name:@"lowlighton" object:nil];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(clicklowlightoff:) name:@"lowlightoff" object:nil];
}
```

Then this code for changing the image:

```
- (void)clicklowlighton:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
    [[self multiPageView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgipad"]]];

}
- (void)clicklowlightoff:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
     [[self multiPageView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bglowlight@2x"]]];

}
```

I only get the `clicklowlightoff` notification, I didn't get the first notification...any missing in my code?

Comment: why do you change the state of switch? [switchControll setOn:YES animated:YES]; ??

Comment: @Ubersoldat to check it is on or not..is that a error?

Comment: no, i mean, you are trying to set it to "ON" while it is already "ON". Why?

Comment: @Ubersoldat ,no.i set it to off in interface builder ....

Comment: you are setting it in your code, not interface builder. if(switchControll.on){ [switchControll setOn:YES animated:YES];} i mean this.

Comment: @Ubersoldat ohh tahts correct,,but i comment this line and run the app,the same poblm occurs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10590/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-ubersoldat)

Answer (score 0):

bind your function to event: UIControlEventValueChanged to this function

```
-(IBAction)_clickswitchlowlight:(id)sender
    {

    if(switchControll.on){

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_lowlighton object:nil];
    }
    else{

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_lowlightoff object:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: it not working,,io put a alert view in the lowlightoff in main page ..when the switch on or of it shows the alert.- (void)clicklowlightoff:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
     [[self multiPageView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bglowlight@2x"]]];
//here i put a alert view
}

Comment: bind your function to event: UIControlEventValueChanged to this function what does it mean?thanks

Comment: drag and drop uicontroleventvaluechanged linker to this function and unlink others